# WPF page layout control selection

Tags: wpf, controls

I have an imagebrush of a soccer field as the page background and I want to be able create a line up by dragging players off the bench and positioning them on the field accordingly.  I don't know what control to use for the background that allows the PlayerCard control to reside where it is dragged.  Any help as to how to begin would be appreciated.

You can get the idea here.

[What control to use?](https://cartesia.pbworks.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the [Canvas container control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx). It lets you arbitrarily place child controls with a Left and Top attached property, similar to the way Windows Forms does it.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll take a look.  And for future reference, could you extend me the courtesy of letting me finish the question before you give me the perfect answer?  <g>

Thanks again.

Comment: Haha I will have to wait until Jeff gives Stack Overflow the ability to look into the future! At the rate he's adding features I'm sure that's not far off.